# Is it possible to have transferable utility in non-cooperative games?

Tags: game-theory

Transferable utility is a concept that seems to be associated with cooperative game theory and coalitions. I would like to know if there are any examples of transferable utility in non-cooperative game theory.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in a lot of mechanism design uses money and assumes agents' valuations are quasilinear. So monetary payments are essentially "transferable utility".